# Make function guarantee certain property is defined

Tags: typescript

Given the following code (also available on [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCSwIFsoF4oG8BQUoDsIBnJAEwC4soBLCqEgJ2vwHMoBfbT7USKAZWABDJOiy4aSZAH5KcRCi7ZsAYwD2+ElAAWQogtQYAFCRERKgswEp0APnF4GEYAFcG+esKQA6alKgAhGgYLvikEABmzBCkSqoaWkTMLAA2zhoWXtAYOHh+KJSh4VGEsdwRoSrA1BpQasDaEAxGNrn0yWnAGr7+OQTEZJSYNHQA5ADuagwppKMcHHEV+FU1HshCzC0OdQ1NLcp5EVBGAbr6UiYd6fhWNk6u7gDcB1Dqmmpp3ilqLEYABo0Ut8oAASTBJVidbr5ZDeQgkGK+UjsP5WOLrTZWIA)),

```
type MyItem = {
  nested: { id: string }
}

type State = {
  item?: MyItem
}

const hasItem = (state: State) => {
  return state.item !== undefined
}

const singleton: State = {
  item: undefined
}

function other() {
  singleton.item = { nested: { id: 'world' } }
}

function main() {
  other()

  if (!hasItem(singleton)) return;

  console.log(`hello ${singleton.item.nested.id}`) // ---> singleton.item is type-erroring
}

main()
```

Is there any way I can make `hasItem(...)` ensures `singleton.item` is defined when it returns `true`?

Comment: Make it a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), e.g. `state is Required<State>`? (Or, more generally, `State & Required<Pick<State, "item">>`.)

Comment: Alright, that's pretty much it - `type predicate` is the word I was looking for. Addressed. Thanks!

Comment: Does @jonrsharpe want to write an answer or find a suitable dupe target? How should we proceed here?